# How do I enable OS X style 2 finger scolling in Dell Latitude 6430u?

Tags: touchpad

I've got a Dell Latitude 6430u running Trusty. I can enable 2 finger scrolling, but it's a bizarre mode where if I put one finger down I can scroll with the other.

I would like to have OS X style two finger scrolling, where dragging two fingers up or down the touchpad scrolls. This apparently works on this model in Windows, so I assume it can be done in Ubuntu.

- My friend's Thinkpad X230 does proper OSX-style scrolling so I am wondering if this is a driver specific issue or a configuration issue?
- Two finger scrolling does work, it just behaves differently than on other laptops.

Any notions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here, and it's all dependent on making sure you're using a synaptics touch device.

In trusty 14.04 there is a natural scrolling feature available if the system detects you are on a synaptics device:

[image: 2 finger natural scrolling]

You may need to blacklist the i2c module

```
echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

The final option, if all else fails, is by adding a PPA to add the Natural Scrolling application:

Add ‘ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling‘ to your Software Sources, update, then install the ‘naturalscrolling’ package from the Ubuntu Software Centre.